# Finding polynomial with discriminant

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, discriminant

Is there an easy method, given a degree $d$ and discriminant $D$, to find a polynomial $P(x)$ with degree $d$ and discriminant $D$.

The example I am looking to solve is a polynomial $P(x)$, degree $6$ with the discriminant $D=-7^5*29^2*337^2$.

I came across a slightly less harder problem, to find a polynomial $P(x)$, degree $4$ with discriminant $D=5^3*11^2*61^2$.

Please help explain how to or find these polynomials (in general given a specific degree and discriminant.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier than you think: the discriminant of $x^n-c$ is $n^n c^{n-1}$. (One can have lots of fun proving this by grinding out the resultant of $x^n-c$ and its derivative $nx^{n-1}$: it should be sparse enough to make this fairly straightforward, if rather heavy on paper use.)

Comment: This is easy to prove by writing the discriminant in terms of the square of the Vandermonde determinant. For $c=1$, the Vandermonde matrix of the roots is $\sqrt n$ times the DFT matrix, which has determinant $1$, so the Vandermonde determinant is $\pm n^{n/2}$ and the discriminant is $n^n$. For arbitrary $c$, each factor of $\prod_{i< j} (r_i -r_j)^2$ multiplies by $c^{2/n}$, and the discriminant increases by a factor of $c^{2/n \binom n2} = c^{n-1}$.

Comment: Very nice! Didn't spot that at all.